# Powershell: Output collection of objects

Tags: powershell

I have a collection of objects with properties:

```
$col = @{....}
```

and the data is something like this:

```
id     name     items
---    ----     -----
01     a        (a, b, c, d)
02     ....
```

items are array of strings. If I output the content of $col, the data are displayed as above. Is there any way to output values like this?

```
id     name     items
---    ----     -----
01     a        a
                b
                c
                d
02     b         
03     c        c1
04     d        d1
                d2
05 ...
```

Updated, the items column may contain empty, one or more than one items.

Comment: I know this question was already answered but I thought I would offer my answer from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723954/powershell-autosize-and-specific-column-width/22724702#22724702) as an alternative since I think it is a little more versatile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First I setup something which is approximately your object, to test with:

```
$col = @(

    (New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop @{'id'='01';'name'='a';'items'=@(1,2,3)}),
    (New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop @{'id'='02';'name'='b';'items'=@(1,2,3)}),
    (New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop @{'id'='03';'name'='c';'items'=@(1,2,3)})
    )
```

Then print it:

```
$col

name id items    
---- -- -----    
a    01 {1, 2, 3}
b    02 {1, 2, 3}
c    03 {1, 2, 3}
```

Then define a custom format rule for the 'Items' column, which joins the collection items together using the newline character:

```
$itemFormat = @{Expression={($_.items -join "`n")};Label="Items";width=6}
```

Then print the collection with Format-Table, using `-Wrap` to allow it to wrap the long lines:

```
$col | Format-Table id,name,$itemFormat -Wrap -AutoSize
```

Which gives:

```
id name Items
-- ---- ------
01 a    1     
        2     
        3     
02 b    1     
        2     
        3     
03 c    1     
        2     
        3
```

Comment: I am trying your solution now. One thing I realize is that items may contain empty or only one item such as "1". In this case, the join would not work. My question is a simplified one. Any way to handle items with empty, one or array of string values?

Comment: I have updated my question with more example of column items.

Comment: @David.Chu.ca I would try changing the format Expression to be `@($_.items) -join` which will force it into an array. I think this will work for empty, single and multiple values in 'items'.