# Expand arrays in console output

Tags: powershell

Take the following PowerShell as an example:

```
$Properties = @{Name='Bob'; Title='Manager'; Ties=@('Red','Green','Corn flower blue', 'Magenta', 'Yellow')}
$Person = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties

$Person

Title   Name Ties
-----   ---- ----
Manager Bob  {Red, Green, Corn flower blue, Magenta...}
```

Is there any way to expand the array in the console output, such that all elements are always visible?  E.g.:

```
$Person

Title   Name Ties
-----   ---- ----
Manager Bob  Red
             Green
             Corn flower blue
             Magenta
             Yellow
```

Outputting multiple objects would look like this:

```
Title   Name Ties
-----   ---- ----
Manager Bob  Red
             Green
             Corn flower blue
             Magenta
             Yellow
CEO     Brad Green
             Blue
             Violet
             Black
             Red
             Brown
             Gray
             Vermilion
Sales   John White
             Off-white
             Mother of pearl
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723954/powershell-autosize-and-specific-column-width) might help you. Your might even be a duplicate.

Comment: One way is to iterate the property that has potential multiples and output a separate object for each.